# importing .csv files into SQlite through objective C

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, csv

I am able to import .csv files into a SQlite table through the command line. It works nice and fine. What i wanted to know was is it possible to do the exact same thing through Objective C code..meaning execute commands like .mode csv && .import file.csv table.

The interface sqlite3 does all normal SQL statement execution like selecting, deleting etc..But i am not sure about the importing part.

Any guidance anyone? Thanks in advance
Regards

Answer (score 2):

You can try the virtual table described on the [ImportingFiles page](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ImportingFiles).  However, you may best off just using an existing Objective-C CSV parser, then inserting each row yourself (within a transaction).  See 
[Anyone know of a good csv to NSArray parser for objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344628/anyone-know-of-a-good-csv-to-nsarray-parser-for-objective-c)
 for a start.

Comment: Thanks for your response guys. Actually, i came across a few parsers(and efficient ones too), but my feeling was if there was support in SQLite itself, i should be using it. Thats why i wanted to go with the import rather than try parsing myself or use a wrapper. Anyways I'm trying it with the virtual table features. Thanks again

Comment: how to direct import csv file to sqlite database objective c