# Converting CSV File to NSArray of NSDictionaries

Tags: objective-c

I have a CSV file with data structured as follows:

40.697776,-73.973605,"1 CARLTON AVENUE, BROOKLYN, NEW YORK,"

40.812784,-73.952996,"1 CONVENT AVENUE, MANHATTAN, NEW YORK,"

I would like to convert each row into an NSDictionary with an NSArray holding all of the dictionaries. I would like the keys for be latitude, longitude, address.

I am new to objective c so I'm have some issues figuring this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing that will do it automatically. You'll need to use an existing [csv parser](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser#readme) or write your own. Start with an empty `NSMutableArray`, then loop through every row in the CSV file. For each row, start with an `NSMutableDictionary` and add the values one at a time. When the row is finished, add the `NSMutableDictionary` to the end of the `NSMutableArray`. The code would look something like below, but the it really depends on which CSV parser you use:

```
NSMutableArray* allRows = [NSMutableArray array];

//how this loop is actually done depends on your CSV parser
//if it's a SAX style parser, then it won't even be a loop, it will be a callback
for(every row in the CSV file) { 
   //how you get these three fields also depends on your CSV parser
   NSNumber* firstField = ?; 
   NSNumber* secondField = ?; 
   NSString* thirdField = ?; 

   NSMutableDictionary* row = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
   [row setObject:firstField forKey:@"latitude"];
   [row setObject:secondField forKey:@"longitude"];
   [row setObject:thirdField forKey:@"address"];
   [allRows addObject:row];
}
```

Comment: But if you're like me, you'd probably want to go check out @DaveDeLong's CSV parser [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344628/where-can-i-find-a-csv-to-nsarray-parser-for-objective-c)

Comment: @Mazyod which Tom linked to in his answer ;)