# How to read this file in the objective c and pass in the array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find a CSV to NSArray parser for Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344628/where-can-i-find-a-csv-to-nsarray-parser-for-objective-c)

I have the CSV file like this:
vv       pp

96.84686 86.38099

How to read this file in the objective c and pass in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some open source csv parser available search on google for that. you will find one in github. Here is one to help you https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser

Comment: Hi rahul... i just downloaded the file from the link you said.. i just want to know how to use that file with my project or how to call my csv file in to that project.. I am new to coding... so this may be a silly question to you... Thanks in Advance

Comment: follow this link http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/11/writing-parser-using-nsscanner-csv.html

Comment: That's not a csv file - csv would be `96.84686,86.38099` - you have space separated. If you want to use the link in the answer, you will also need to do this : `parser setDelimiter:@" ";`

Comment: @deanwombourne Thanks for pointing out the information

Comment: thanks for the link.. n sorry my csv file has 96.84686,86.38099 in this format only.. while typing i made a mistake..