# Reading 'CSV' file in xCode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, csv

Could you please help me for reading this csv file?

### CSV Output

"^GSPC",1403.36,"4/27/2012","4:32pm",+3.38,1400.19,1406.64,1397.31,574422720
"^IXIC",3069.20,"4/27/2012","5:30pm",+18.59,3060.34,3076.44,3043.30,0

### ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *absoluteURL = @"http://myserver/data.csv";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:absoluteURL];
    NSString *fileString = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:fileString];
    [scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:
    [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\n, "]];
    NSMutableArray *newPoints = [NSMutableArray array];

}
```

Comment: Try this method: - (NSArray *)componentsSeparatedByString: (NSString *)separator;

Comment: Could u please tell me, how can i read this file content as a string? 'initWithContentsOfURL' is not working here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handling CSV parsing is a lot tricker than your initial code implies, because quoted separators need to be ignored. For example,

```
1,"Hello, world!",2
```

has three columns, but `NSScanner` would find four tokens (`1`, `"Hello`, "world!", and `2`).

There are many special cases to handle in order to build a full-featured CSV parser, so the fastest way to get it working is to use a pre-built one. For example, you could use the parser described in [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3380724/335858).

Answer (score 0):

I might be too late to answer this but may be this answer can help someone to read CSV file with ease. This is what i Have don't to read CSV file

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
   //  printing the file path

      NSMutableArray *colA = [NSMutableArray array];
      NSMutableArray *colB = [NSMutableArray array];
   NSMutableArray *colC = [NSMutableArray array];
   NSMutableArray *colD = [NSMutableArray array];
  //  NSString* fileContents = [NSTemporaryDirectory() 
stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourfile.csv"];
NSString *fileContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
 pathForResource:@"yourfile" ofType:@"csv"];

  NSURL*URl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileContents];

  //        NSString* fileContents = [NSString 
stringWithContentsOfURL:@"YourFile.csv"];
   NSError *error;
  NSString* fileContentss = (NSString *)[NSString 
 stringWithContentsOfURL:URl encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding 
error:&error];

   NSMutableArray *newArra = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   [fileContentss stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" 
  withString:@""];
      NSArray* rows = [fileContentss 
   componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

   NSMutableArray *roearr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   roearr = [rows mutableCopy];


    [roearr removeObjectAtIndex:[rows count] - 1];
      for (NSString *row in roearr){



          NSArray* columns = [row componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

          newArra = [columns mutableCopy];

         [newArra removeObjectAtIndex:[newArra count] - 1];
            [colA addObject:newArra[0]];
            [colB addObject:newArra[1]];
            [colC addObject:newArra[2]];
            [colD addObject:columns[3]];
       }

     NSLog(@"columns[0] %@",colA);
    NSLog(@"columns[0] %@",colB);
    NSLog(@"columns[0] %@",colC);
    NSLog(@"columns[0] %@",colD);


   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from 
  a nib.
  }
```