# How to convert csv file data into NSMutabledictionary

Tags: iphone, csv, nsmutablearray

I want to parse the csv data with live link and convert the same in NSMutabledictionary.Here is the link that i am using for csv file.

http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=BAS.DE&d=2&e=30&c=2012

Please help me out for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344628/where-can-i-find-a-csv-to-nsarray-parser-for-objective-c/3380724#3380724..visit this post

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://rndm-snippets.blogspot.com/2011/08/xcode4-csv-parser-for-iphoneipad-ios.html) link should have what you need. But, do you download that link as file into your app directory? If so, after importing `parseCSV`, it is fairly easy to go through the lines of the csv file:

```
CSVParser *parser = [CSVParser new];
NSString *csvFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myCsvFile" ofType:@"csv"];
[parser openFile:csvFilePath];
NSArray *csvContentArray = [parser parseFile];

for (int i=0; i<csvContentArray.count; i++)
    NSLog(@"parsed %d %@", i, [csvContentArray objectAtIndex:i]);

[parser closeFile];
```