# How to parse CSV files for Iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, csv

I am working on a iphone project . I want to parse a CSV file. From whatever I found, the

libraries available for CSV parsing is only for MAC , not for iphone. I want a simple approach

for parsing CSV file only for iphone. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: See: [Where can I find a CSV to NSArray parser for Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3344628/1402846).

Answer (score 4):

This is a nice CSV parser with support for streams: https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser

If you are parsing a file that comes from the web, then you could also use https://github.com/acerbetti/AFCSVRequestOperation which is using the AFNetworking library for downloading the file.

Answer (score 0):

CSV is basically a comma separated list of values. You can use `NSString` methods `componentsSeparatedByString:` or `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` for that.

Suppose you have a comma separated string, calling `[myStringCSV componentsSeparatedByString:@","]` will give you an `NSArray` with the values.

Comment: This is an oversimplification - what will componentsSeparatedByString method do with this perfectly valid CSV: string, "another,string"? Make three elements out of two! You'd better use a library that knows how to manage all the corner cases like the one suggested by Edwin Vermeer: CHCSVParser.

Comment: Just filter out empty elements, no big deal.