# iOS easy way to convert and store large table

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, excel

I have Excel file with table ~100x100 and need to get access to this values from iOS app.
[image]

At first, I've try to make json in [Mr.DataConverter](http://www.shancarter.com/data_converter/index.html) and then it's not a problem to read to array. But! Some float values didn't recognized properly, and I'd got numbers without quotes:
[image]

At the time other parsed correctly! 
So, from this moment I can't parse my Json string to NSArray.

The question is:
How to convert xls to json, OR How to put and retrieve the values in iOS device?

Thanks.

Comment: Export to CSV then [parse the CSV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344628/where-can-i-find-a-csv-to-nsarray-parser-for-objective-c).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend [exporting](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-HP010342598.aspx) the Excel spreadsheet to CSV and then using a proper [CSV parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344628/where-can-i-find-a-csv-to-nsarray-parser-for-objective-c) to parse the data. If you run into any issues then there is likely an issue in the spreadsheet that you would need to fix.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [DHlibxls iOS Framework](https://github.com/dhoerl/DHlibxls) and simply pull the .xls file into your app, then read and process with that framework. The framework is based on the open source libxls library on SourceForge, and has a non-attributed BSD license.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative: If possible use excel file in formate: tab delimited-text-file. That solve all your problem. Easy to open text file in iOS with file manager/c++.

[convert-an-excel-spreadsheet-to-a-tab-delimited-text-file](http://www.howtogeek.com/79991/convert-an-excel-spreadsheet-to-a-tab-delimited-text-file/)